# Add new rows automatically in Partitioned Table using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I have a table in Big Query which is getting daily updated with new rows. I have created a new partitioned table using Partition by Date with date column to reduce execution time and cost. But, I need to daily automatically update the partitioned table with new data as well. How should this be implemented ? Iam a newbie in Bigquery, thus need help.

Comment: Can you refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples) to stream data into partitioned tables in BigQuery. Let me know if it’s helpful or not?

Comment: Are you streaming or just inserting? You can treat it like any other table if you're just inserting.

Comment: Hi @prestyprajna, If you find my answer helpful, please consider to accept & upvote it as per [Stack Overflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), helping more Stack contributors with their researches. If not, let me know so that I can improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to Load data into a column-based time partitioning table.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema=[
        bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("post_abbr", "STRING"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("date", "DATE"),
    ],
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    time_partitioning=bigquery.TimePartitioning(
        type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
        field="date",  # Name of the column to use for partitioning.
        expiration_ms=7776000000,  # 90 days.
    ),
)
uri = "gs://cloud-samples-data/bigquery/us-states/us-states-by-date.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Wait for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)
print("Loaded {} rows to table {}".format(table.num_rows, table_id))
```

For more information about the partitioned tables you can refer this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#:%7E:text=You%20can%20partition%20BigQuery%20tables,based%20on%20an%20integer%20column.).